# Proof for All rows/cols for A has same sum $s$ $\implies$ $s$ is an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To prove for All rows/cols for A has same sum $s$ $\implies$ $s$ is an eigenvalue

So in order for $s$ to be an eigenvalue, it has to satisfy Ax=$\lambda$x where x$\ne 0$. But how do you simplify A to find $\lambda$?

Someone please help?

Comment: You don't need to simplify the matrix.. try to find a nice $x$. Which $x$ can exploit the fact that the sums are the same?

Comment: I wonder if the all one vector would be an eigenvector to some special eigenvalue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Find $Au$ for $u=(1,1,1,1,....,1)^T$ ( all components$= 1$).